# Добавить тип файла в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Добра всем!

Реально добавить окончание ***.GIF** к ссылке через **.htaccess** или еще как?

Скрипт PHP генерирует картинку, хедер выводит. Т.е. картинка в браузере получается по ссылке _http://sait.ru/u/1
**Хотелось бы так _http://sait.ru/u/1.GIF**

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
RewriteRule ^/u/([0-9]+) /u/$1.GIF [R=301,L]
```

Если вам надо, чтобы по запросу `/u/1.GIF` информация как бы бралась с `/u/1`, то так:

```
RewriteRule ^/u/([0-9]+).GIF /u/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает!

u.php - это файл, который обрабатывает GET запрос.

1 - в примере это ID юзера.

_http://sait.ru/u/1.gif - вот так не работает.

Comment: @WEBOG ну так указывайте верно данные, попробуйте так:

    RewriteRule ^/u/([0-9]+).GIF /u.php?param=$1 [L]

где param - это передаваемый номер.

Comment: Тоже что-то не то.

Вот мой .htaccess:

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine on

######убрать *.php в конце#######
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ $1.php [NC]
#################################

RewriteRule ^u/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ u.php?id=$1&url=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^u/(.*)$ /u.php?id=$1

#####.GIF#######
#RewriteRule ^/u/([0-9]+).GIF /u/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^/u/([0-9]+).GIF /u.php?id=$1 [L]
################

Comment: у вас последнее условие по идее перехватывает моё условие

Comment: Возможно! Как победить?

Мне обработать две ссылки

http://sait.ru/u/1/url - ссылка
http://sait.ru/u/1 - изображение

Comment: Уважаемые гуру, есть еще варианты?